# React Native integration with identity server

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, pkce

I have a react native app which is created using react-native-cli.

In official react native documentation it recommends to use react-native-app-auth which has too many issues reported.

However since it’s used by many i have started my implementation but came across many issues related Android.

Is there a recommended library that is maintained or tutorial that provides the guide to implement authentication using authorization code flow with PKCE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AppAuth are the official libraries, though they are easier to integrate into a Kotlin based app, since the tech gets quite native in places:

- Opening a Chrome Custom Tab
- Registering redirect schemes
- An Authorization Code Flow redirect
- An Authorization Code Grant POST
- A Refresh Token Grant POST
- Secure storage of tokens on the device
- Good login usability
- Handling error and expiry conditions

AppAuth is primarily a pattern though, from [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252), so you could implement the above in Javascript code.

Start by implementing the above 3 OAuth messages and ensure that you understand payloads. Post back if you get stuck on areas such as PKCE and I can point you to some relevant JS code.

**TRICKY AREAS**

My [Android Blog Posts](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) may help you to clarify your requirements and explains some common problems and resolutions. There is a detailed code sample you can run locally also.

**MOBILE TECH**

I had a React Native sample in the past, but found the tech too painful in some areas:

- Missing error details in responses from React-Native-App-Auth
- Red screens when tracing HTTPS requests.

Therefore I switched everything to Kotlin where there are fewer tech layers to deal with.

Comment: @Gray Thanks a lot for detailed info. I will start implementation using Javascript code and get back to you if i get stuck in any area.